# Custom Fonts User Script: Revert or Improve the Font Updates

Tags: discussion, formatting, userscript

Recently, Stack Exchange decided to [switch to system fonts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021?cb=1). For those of you who prefered the old appearance, or would like a different font to appear in code blocks or across the site as a whole, Custom Fonts is a user script I wrote this morning to allow just that.

#### Features

Custom Fonts allows rules to be set for different sites, which can specify a sans serif, serif, and monospace font. A default can also be specified, allowing you to choose between sans serif and serif for any site.

Custom Fonts initially doesn't change anything (unless you download one with a preset), but on lines 26 and 27 are rules that revert all of Stack Exchange to its original fonts (once un-commented). Custom rules can be written, and there is a short reference in the comments under the `Rules` object.

#### Download

Custom Fonts is a user script, meaning that it requires Greasemonkey (Firefox or browsers that support Firefox extensions) or Tampermonkey (Chrome or browsers that support Chrome extensions) to be installed.

**[Custom Fonts 1.2.4](https://github.com/RedwolfPrograms/userscripts/raw/main/custom-fonts.user.js)**

**[Custom Fonts 1.2.4, with original fonts](https://gist.github.com/RedwolfPrograms/35c237ee02015b60d643f61a6f2570a1/raw/411d70cf08dca4c6d21003cad81915ca698bcf78/custom-fonts-1.2.4-arial.user.js)**

**[Custom Fonts 1.2.4, with Roboto + Roboto Mono](https://gist.github.com/RedwolfPrograms/6587a7fb499a43e72d4ec24f4dc42df0/raw/296fcf46451326b13aa26a534fbf2623758c0ff7/custom-fonts-1.2.4-roboto.user.js)**

Comment: Is there any benefit to using a user script over a user stylesheet?

Comment: @Adám Not really, but for people who don't have user stylesheet tools installed this is a very easy way to insert (and customize) the needed CSS

Comment: Thanks. For configuration I found that looks best with php.net's fonts: `var sans = '"Fira Sans", "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif';` and `var mono = '"Fira Mono", "Source Code Pro", monospace';`.